# Android: no such table "android_metadata"

Tags: android, sqlite

При открытии базы вываливается эксепшн с указанной ошибкой, причем только на некоторых устройствах (в частности, HTC Desire, HTC Wildfire), на самсунгах и других все работает.
А вообще, происходит копирование базы из assets в `/data/data/package.name/databases/`.
Сталкивался ли кто с подобной ошибкой? Как решили?

Знаю, что нужно указать в `openDataBase()` флаг `NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS`, но проблема происходит при вызове `getReadableDatabase()`, который по-видимому при открытии базы не использует данный флаг.

Как вариант: можно попытаться создать таблицу ручками в уже существующей базе, либо программно, но для создания таблицы программно, база-то должна быть открыта.

Странное совпадение еще в том, что на данных двух девайсах нельзя получить права root. Хотя данную табличку-то создает сама система.

Comment: Еще один вариант: переопределяю методы помощника getReadableDatabase()/getWritableDatabase() и там указываю данный флаг,но неуверен что поможет и хочется найти еще варианты.

Comment: А почему не создать таблицу вручную, как описано в статье, ссылку на которою Вы дали?

Comment: Потому что неизвестно, как будет на девайсах, где данной проблемы нет. Собственно, я написал код, который в catch это и делает (создает эту таблицу), но гарантий никаких нет, потому интересно мнения тех, у кого такое было. Кроме того, система сама создает эту таблицу в каждой sqlite БД.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если такое происходит, то скорее всего банально нет этой таблицы(система не смогла ее создать) из-за неверного использования вами класса SQLiteOpenHelper, по разным причинам, например из-за конкуренции потоков.

Возможный выход:

- Отказаться от использовать данного класса помощника вообще и использовать методы класса Context
- Использовать методы onCreate()/onUpgrade() класса SQLiteOpenHelper. В onCreate() выполнять запросы и если необходимо заполнять базу данными, а в onUpgrade() обновлять версию БД, вызывая по условию onCreate()